# android layout image at left and two text block at right

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I want a layout like this
[Layout where an image at the bottom and two text block at right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUimp.png)

It's a very simple layout with an image at left and two text blocks at right. I know how to do this in html and `CSS` but no idea how to do this in `XML`. What are the properties to float elements left or right? Right now if I add an image and two text blocks, the second text block is not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit it on your own :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, I've tested it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The imageView doesn't have to be inside a LinearLayout. You could just remove the parent linearLayout and give the weight-property to the imageView instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relative layout for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:src="@drawable/ic_clear"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:text="text 1"/>
    <TextView android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:text="text 2"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```